# Twitter RSS feed for share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a twitter rss feed for my share point 2013.
I am following the link: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/add-rss-feeds-from-external-sites-to-your-site-HA102851053.aspx to create a RSS web part.

I just don't know how to link it to my twitter account. Or what do I need to do to create a twitter rss feed web part.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has no RSS feeds for you to use, you would have to either write functionality against the twitter API or sign up for a third-party service giving you RSS from your twitter account